# An unexpected space instead of the unnecessary checkbox label

Tags: javascript, checkbox, webix

Developing UI with Webix. There's an unhoped problem: I'm trying to set label alignment to the right side of the checkbox, but when I'm using labelRight, there is an unexpected space before the control, as if the left label exist. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Just set `labelWidth:0` like this:

```
{ view:"checkbox", 
  width:110, 
  labelRight:"SomeText", 
  labelWidth:0 
},
```